# How to maintain high volume of data using Angularjs-2?

Tags: angular, gridview

I need to manage a huge volume of data in an HTML grid. For that, I have tried AG-Grid, ng2-virtual-scroll and Vaadin-grid

It is working fine in google chrome and others. But the performance of these frameworks is very slow in IE

Is there any other frameworks to handle huge volume of data and also works fine in IE?

Answer (score 2):

When having to deal with huge volumes, you should really investigate if the default change detection that Angular uses is suitable for you. You might want to investigate setting the changeDetectionStrategy to onPush. Read more [here](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/05/04/angular-2-best-practices-change-detector-performance/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Infragistics IGGrid for millions of data. Performance is quite good in all browsers with 20 columns and 100 pagesize. I also use multiple grid at the same time. It also have angular 2 support. Please go through this link https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular2